# Make condition only if "something" - Query Oracle

Tags: oracle, case

i'm with a problem in a query.

I have a table called "store" that I need to query.

```
Select s.store_name
  from store s
 where s.store = case
                    when p_store != 0 then
                       p_store
                    else
                       s.store
                    end;
```

This should work but as I have "stores" with characters (-) in column and this is defined as number, that query raise an exception: ORA-01722: invalid number.
So I want to do something like this in query:

```
IF p_store != 0 then
   select store_name from store where store = p_store
else
   select store_name from store;
```

Is it possible?
Thanks!

EDIT: 
The query that I wrote above was an example of the query I was running.
The exception was raised because another column (too much hours in front of PC :-( ). 
This table have a column that's varchar2(15) and I was doing this condition:
    (...)AND S.CODE > 4 (...)
The correct condition that I want to do is:
    (...)AND LENGTH(S.CODE) > 4
Thank you all!

Comment: "... and *this* is defined as number..."  - I missed it, what does "this" refer to? Who is "this" in the sentence?

Comment: Anyway, the second version does not work (besides the fact that there is no "if" in Oracle SQL, you can't have different SELECT statements in the branches of a CASE statement). It would help to define the problem better first, though. What is the issue - s.store is VARCHAR2 and you must compare to a p_store input as a number?

Comment: Sorry, the column "store" is defined as number. So when p_store = 0, the exception is raised because is there some "stores" with the character '-'.

Comment: The problem is: s.store is VARCHAR2 and I must compare to a p_store input

Comment: Are you saying the column "store" in the table has data type NUMBER, but some values have a '-' in them? Like perhaps 312-20? That should not be possible - you can't store non-numerical data in Oracle. (There are ways to store invalid data in the database, but it shouldn't happen in the normal course of business.)  Are you SURE the data in the database is of NUMBER data type?

Comment: Oh, I see...   So, why is p_store a number and not a VARCHAR2? In any case, if it comes in as a number, use to_char(p_store) and '0' in the query (make everything varchar2).

Comment: The problem is: s.store is NUMBER(4) but I don't know how, I have some store e.g. "-122" .
When I'm going to compare, the exception is raised. I must compare s.store to a p_store input.

I wrote the second version only to explain the solution (logic) that I think that could solve my problem. 

PS: The exception is raise when p_store = 0, so it's when p.store = p.store. Little strange not?

Comment: OK. So, if a store is shown as -122, should that in fact be 122? Instead of the answer I now removed (because it was based on wrong understanding on my part), where you can make p_store a string, you can rather make store into a number. But that depends on where the - is in the number, and whether removing it is the right thing. (Not hard to do, but is it the RIGHT THING to do?)

Comment: By the way, -122 is OK as number (it's a negative number - it may not make sense as a store number!) but if you had 1-22 that would be much stranger.

Comment: When I comment the "else s.store", the exceptions isn't raised. So the problem is only when I have s.store = s.store. 
This is very strange.

The - is the first character.

Comment: And what is the desired result - should then the number be considered, with the - removed?

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show the table definition, p_store declaration, and sample data and actual values that generate the error. You shouldn't be trying to explain everything in comments, and what you have tried to explain is contradictory.

Comment: Post was edited, I find where problem was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you have varchar2 `s.store` which in fact contains numbers so Oracle tries to compare it casting to numbers but at some point it gets `-` and throws an exception. What you should do is update on table replacing `-` by `null`. But if you don't want to do that you can try to make case return `varchar2`

```
Select s.store_name
  from store s
 where s.store = case
                    when to_char(p_store) != '0' then
                       to_char(p_store)
                    else
                       s.store
                    end;
```

Comment: A bug here... What about when p_store is null

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are running the query in a plsql block (as cursor?). In that case dynamic sql is the way to go. check out REF CURSOR too (google!).